# Maven Angular 6 deployment on tomcat

Tags: angular, maven

helo i am using plugin to build war file and angular 6 project

In my pom.xml i have used below plugin to build

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
             <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.22</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution> 




                <!-- It will execute command "npm install" inside "/e2e-angular2" directory -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
        <arguments>install --proxy=http://proxy.company.com:80 --no-proxy</arguments>
    </configuration>
                </execution>
              <!--   It will execute command "npm build" inside "/e2e-angular2" directory 
                    to clean and create "/dist" directory -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
              <configuration>
        <nodeVersion>v5.7.1</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>3.6.0</npmVersion>
    </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Plugin to copy the content of /angular/dist/ directory to output directory (ie/ /target/transactionManager-1.0/) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/${angular.project.location}/dist</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

But i am getting following error when i do mvn clean install

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.22:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project agacf-root: Could not download Node.js from: http://nodejs.org/dist/v5.7.1/x64/node.exe: Could not download http://nodejs.org/dist/v5.7.1/x64/node.exe: Unknown host nodejs.org -> [Help 1]

Do i required any specific version of this NodeJs or Maven plugin that i am using?

In my maven setting.xml

I have proxy set as

```
    <proxies>
    <proxy>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>https</protocol>
  <host>proxy.company.com</host>
  <port>80</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>maven.company.com|*.other.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: In my maven setting.xml    i am having proxy, added in my question